# Sign in to GitLab CE repository in TeamCity

Tags: gitlab, teamcity

When try get access from `TeamCity` on page `VSC Roots` to `Gitlab CE` repositorys get an error message:

```
Empty error response from https://gitlab.prod.com/oauth/token, status code: 504 (teamcity_invalid_response) 
Connection: GitLab CE/EE (project: XTestConnection)
```

In browser or command line successful connection to Gitlab CE and GitLab API is available.If manually paste a url repository Gitlab CE to field `Fetch URL`, i can run builds in TeamCity, all works.

But it only works if the `git@gitlab.prod.com:project/test.git`, but not `https://gitlab.prod.com/project/test.git`, and works only with uploaded SSH key authentication, not login/pass.

Between servers I don’t have a proxy, open full access. However, there is a NGINX proxy from the gitlab ce omnybus installation.

How to reproduce:

TeamCity, authorize using LDAP (Windows AD), but I tried to create a local internal account for the test.
GitLab authorizes using created credentials inside, without using third-party OAuth

```
LDAP: ... LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml
Checking LDAP ... Finished
```

Original link https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/360787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the wrong value system var `TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS` on master server TeamCity

My GitLab CE is located at `https://gitlab.prod.com`, but the value was not specified by `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.prod.com` to exclude local addresses